# Example south schema migration for inserting a model in a hierarchy

Tags: django, django-south

Struggling to wrap my brains around how to accomplish this: would love to see an example from someone who's done it before!

Assuming, before:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(A)
    pass
```

And the situation I want to get to is:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

class B(C):
    pass
```

How would I go about writing the south migration for this? Do I need to do a 'datamigration'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem (it's a 4-step process). Would still be interested to see if this can be improved/simplified.

1) Create the new model as an independent model, eg.

```
class C(models.Model):
    pass
```

and then do an automatic schema migration (eg: `schemamigration app_name --auto`)

2) Populate the new model `C` with the data from `class A` using a custom datamigration. Eg run `datamigration app_name populate_C` to create a migration skeleton and populate the `id` of the new model with the existing `id` from `A`:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for a in orm.A.objects.all():
        c = orm.C(id=a.id)
        c.save()
```

3) Now do a custom `schemamigration` (by specifying the `--empty` flag) and rename the `id` column in `app_name_c` from `id` to `a_ptr_id`, eg:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.rename_column('app_name_c', 'id', 'a_ptr_id')
```

At this point you can change `class C(models.Model)` to `class C(A)` because the underlying table now reflects this new reality.

4) Do a final custom schemamigration where you rename the 'a_ptr_id' column of 'app_name_b' to 'b_ptr_id', eg:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.rename_column('app_name_b', 'a_ptr_id', 'b_ptr_id')
```

And at this point you can change `class B(A)` to the new reality which is `class B(C)`.

Run the migrations and you've updated your hierarchy!

Comment: Just to point out: you are using data migrations for schema changes. If you are changing database table structure, then they should be schema migrations, not data migrations. Basically, if you are using ``south.db.db.*``, it's a schema migration.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel thanks for pointing this out. I didn't realise you could do custom schema migrations by specifying the `--empty` flag. Based on your feedback I am updating the answer so that steps 3 and 4 are custom `schemamigrations`